Generate unique sequence by using repeated elements
We have 30 places, and the element at each place can be either 'A' or 'T'. AndI want to get all possible result of unique sequence. Some result are like below:
'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'
'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAT'
'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAATA'
'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAATT'
...

I want to get all possible sequence. And the order also matters. Which means
'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAT' != 'TAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA'

So, anyone can help me to deal with this?
My idea is to write a 30 nested for-loops. But I feel this is crazy and too stupid.
I checked the reply, firstly, thanks all of you. My question actually is what is the idea behind such a question. By using itertools module definitely it can solve such a question. However, if I want to reproduce such a module by myself, what should I do?

What would you do if you only had one place which could be A or T? Since each position is independent of the other,  solve for 1, and call 29 times for the remaining string.

You can write a single loop from 0 to 2^30 - 1. Note that there will be ~1bn sequences.

This question is similar to: How to generate all possible strings in python?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This is easy to do with itertools.product:
import itertools
for seq in itertools.product("AT", repeat=30):
    # seq is a tuple of 30 strings
    seq = "".join(seq)
    print(seq)

Do note that this will produce over one billion sequences (2^30), so processing the full list of sequences will take some time.

Given that the question doesn’t have any practical importance, I suspect its goal is to teach how to generate Cartesian products without using itertools.

I don’t think the OP said this was an exercise. It might be a real problem - for example, maybe this is a genomics problem where they have 30 ambiguous A/T reads and want to find all the possible sequences that might result from the data.

I sincerely hope genetic research isn’t underpinned by volunteered time on SO.
